# Angular: How to programatically set select/select2 value after onSubmit()

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I'm using HTML `<select>` Tag, so as it is known allready:

> The  element is used to create a drop-down list.
>
> The  tags inside the  element define the available
>   options in the list.

I want to achieve next thing:

after I select value in a drop-down list I would like to set select's value to a default value which is "-/-" ..

Here is how it looks:

[image]

And code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-sm-3" for="">Select Select2:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="taxSelect" class="form-control dash-form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null" >-/-</option>
      <option *ngFor="let code of codes" [value]="code.id">
        {{code.title}}
      </option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

I mean when I open modal again I want to see "-/-" as it is **default value**, and not the value that I previously selected.. So basically `onSubmit()` in typescript I would like to reset  to set again "-/-" as a default value..

P.S I've tried:

```
show() {

    $('select').val('0');
    $('select').val($('select').children().eq(0).val());

    $('select2').val('0');
    $('select2').val($('select').children().eq(0).val());

    $("select[title='-/-']").attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

So basically when Modal is shown I wanted to reset drop-down values to "-/-" but it doesn't work..

Thanks a lot guys!
CHEERS!